# Download a group of URLs on background using NSURLSession

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, nsurlsession

I'm trying to download some content from the URL list **(about 100 URLs)** using background download (NSURLSession, backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier).

It works fine for one URL, the app downloads data successfully while the user works with other applications.

However, it doesn't start download of the next URL from the series until the user opens the app again.

Is it possible to download a group of URLs on background using NSURLSession? Are there any limitations on number of concurrent downloads?

```
let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier("my-id")

self.session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: self, delegateQueue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue())

self.task = self.session!.downloadTaskWithURL(NSURL(string:self.currentDownloadModel!.downloadUrl)!)

task!.resume()
```

**AppDelegate.swift**

```
//event when app was closed and app was completed after that
func application(application: UIApplication, handleEventsForBackgroundURLSession identifier: String, completionHandler: () -> Void) {

    self.downloadService.handler = completionHandler
}
```

Comment: Simply you can do it using array.Save group of URL in array using add objects.In URL downloading session make the for loop and run it.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Are there any limitation on number of concurrently downloading urls?